# RestSharp GetAsync throws an Exception instead of returning BadResult

Tags: c#, restsharp, http-status-codes

I'm getting an exception instead of a HttpStatusCode.BadResult when I use GetAsync RestSharp method.

> Request failed with status code BadRequest

Let me say that Postman and Swagger return the proper value, so I'm doing something wrong in my code.

It works fine when it returns Ok().

That's my controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    Sysmac dbStore = new();
    var result = await dbStore.AturadesSql.Llista();
    return (dbStore.Error) ? BadRequest(dbStore.ErrorMessage) : Ok(result);
}
```

It simply calls a database procedure and returns an error message in case of error. For the sake of the question I'm forcing that error message to be: 'This is an error'. That is the values returned by Postman.

I tried with this code to avoid network related errors:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    return BadRequest("This is an error");
}
```

And that's my API client method:

```cs
public async Task<APIResult<T>> GetAsync<T>(string apiUrl)
{
    APIResult<T> result = new APIResult<T>();

    try
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(apiUrl);

        var response = await RestClient.GetAsync(request);

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception($"ERROR: API:{apiUrl}  (Status: {response.StatusDescription})");
        }

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            result.Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content, settings);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Error = true;
        result.ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I can't never check `response.StatusCode` because `await RestClient.GetAsync(request)` is throwing the exception.

Comment: This is by (questionable) design: https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html

Comment: @Evk This doc states that: `Normally, RestSharp doesn't throw an exception if the request fails.` So you have to force the exception. I'm doing the test in my local computer, it shouldn't detect network errors.

Comment: It seems you didn't read it to the end. There is a table in the end which shows which functions throw exceptions. If it says "Yes" - it always throws exception on http error. If it says "No" then it does not unless you configured to always throw on errors. The reasoning behind that is explained there also. You can find `GetAsync` in that table.

Comment: @Evk I read it but ThowOnAnyError is not set to true in my code, unless it is true by default. Of course maybe I'm wrong but is says:  "Note that functions, which don't throw by default, will throw exceptions when ThrowOnAnyError is set to true."

Comment: Yes but the point is - `ThrowOnAnyError` has any effect only on functions that do _not_ throw by default, so only on functions with "No" in that table (as your citation says). Functions which have "Yes" _always_ throw on errors, no matter what. It's understandable why `GetAsync<T>` throws, as they mention it does not return full response. But why `GetAsync` throws I don't understand the reasoning for, probably "for consistency".

Comment: @Evk can you show me or point me out to a good example on how to use it?

Comment: Try to use ExecuteAsync instead, it should not throw exception. Consider also move to built-in HttpClient unless RestSharp has something you cannot live without.